# How to pull week to date data and add additional column for percentages

Tags: sql

```
[select trunc(A.late_shpdte) "DNET",
    count(distinct A.ordnum) "Orders",
    count(A.ordlin) "Lines",
    sum(A.uc_ord_line_edi_vfld3) "Total Case"
from (select distinct ord_line.late_shpdte,
            ord_line.ordnum,
            ord_line.ordlin,
            ord_line.prtnum,
            ord_line.host_ordqty,
            ord_line.ordqty,
            ord_line.shpqty,
            ord_line.uc_ord_line_edi_vfld3,
            ord_line.ordqty / prtftp_view.untcas,
            mod((ord_line.ordqty / prtftp_view.untcas), (prtftp_view.untpal / prtftp_view.untcas)) mdd,
            remainder((ord_line.ordqty / prtftp_view.untcas), (prtftp_view.untpal /    prtftp_view.untcas)) rmd,
            mod((ord_line.ordqty / prtftp_view.untcas), (prtftp_view.untpal / prtftp_view.untcas)) -
            case when ord_line.prtnum in (select prtmst.prtnum
                                            from prtmst
                                           where prtmst.wh_id_tmpl = 'US_5035'
                                             and prtmst.prt_client_id = 'JNJ'
                                             and prtmst.rcvflg = '1') then floor((mod((ord_line.ordqty / prtftp_view.untcas), (prtftp_view.untpal / prtftp_view.untcas))) / prtftp.caslvl) * prtftp.caslvl
                 else 0
            end cs_ordqty
       from ord_line
       left
       join prtftp_view
         on ord_line.prtnum = prtftp_view.prtnum
        and ord_line.wh_id = prtftp_view.wh_id
        and ord_line.client_id = prtftp_view.prt_client_id
        and prtftp_view.defftp_flg = '1'
       left
       join prtmst
         on prtmst.prtnum = ord_line.prtnum
        and prtmst.prt_client_id = ord_line.prt_client_id
        and prtmst.wh_id_tmpl = ord_line.wh_id
       left
       join prtftp
         on prtftp.prtnum = ord_line.prtnum
        and prtftp.prt_client_id = prtmst.prt_client_id
        and prtftp.wh_id = prtmst.wh_id_tmpl
        and prtftp.wh_id = '5035'
        and prtftp.defftp_flg = 1
      where trunc(ord_line.late_shpdte) >= sysdate - 3) A
group by trunc(A.late_shpdte)
order by trunc(A.late_shpdte) desc]
```

See image below. Ask is to have DNET for week to date. Additionally, need an additional column that gives the percentage of total cases per day based off sum of total cases for every day.

NA

Comment: A [mcve] is a great start when asking for SQL assistance.